# I want spring boot application which accepts https request and send this request to other app on http and send this http response back to https req

Tags: java, spring, https, mtls

I tried and able to read the CA certificates succsssfully send in request. But when sending request to other app over http getting error as " This combination of host and port required TLS" . Is there any way I can send the request to http and on receiving response, send this response back to https request.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable http on the server you are sending request to.